# named the working directory is not writable

Tags: linux, debian, bind, debian-jessie

I am trying to setup Bind9 on Debian Jessie as described [by Debian's Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9). When I finish, and attempt to start BIND (`service bind9 start`), I get the dreaded FAIL message. Below is the tail of my `/var/log/syslog`:

```
...
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: the working directory is not writable
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/update_debug.log' failed: permission denied
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: configuring logging: permission denied
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: loading configuration: permission denied
Jul  5 20:23:16 debian named[8309]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

I can't seem to get passed here. I created the `chroot` directory structure, double-checked the permissions and commands were run in order, but no change.

What can I do to continue? I do not have SELinux enabled on this system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "working directory is not writable" message is a warning, not really related to the fatal errors that follow. You can silence that message by fixing the permissions on the base directory (which appears to be set to /var/bind9/chroot/var/cache/bind by the directions on that wiki page) but there's no real need to and ***it's safer to NOT fix it.***

The fatal error is the inability to create the file that named thinks is /var/log/update_debug.log but is in fact /var/bind9/chroot/var/log/update_debug.log. I expect this will solve that problem:

```
mkdir /var/bind9/chroot/var/log
chown bind:bind /var/bind9/chroot/var/log
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct directory on standard debian bind9 builds is: `/var/cache/bind`

```
chown -R bind:root /var/cache/bind
rndc reload or service bind9 reload
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

No more errors.

If running chrooted it will depend where you set your directories to, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear; but where do you attempt to start the setup from ? 
Try from /tmp/ or /usr/ if you try from another location, just to be sure of non-local interference.

Did you chown the  /var/named ?
If you did and that didn't work, go to your chroot environment file (BIND.chroot.dist) and change

```
/set type=dir uname=root gname=wheel mode=0644
```

to

```
/set type=dir uname=bind gname=wheel mode=0755
```

Comment: 1. /var/named/ and /etc/mtree/BIND.chroot.dist  are FreeBSD-isms. The OP is using a Debian Wiki How-To that puts the chroot at /var/bind9/ and describes the entirely manual chroot setup one must do on Linux. 
2. "working directory is not writable" is a warning, not a fatal error. The fatal error is in the logging setup.
3. The base directory is not writable by the 'bind' user for a sound security reason: a RCE bug in named would put the whole tree under it at risk.